# Using batch file to list files created or modified in the last 7days

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I'm trying to create a batch file that will look across a folder and its subfolders and list any file that has been created or modified within say the last 7 days. I only want to know files that meet the condition, not folders.

I've played around with DIR command, but whatever I do, it always seems to list everything.

I found this piece of code in Stackoverflow from 2017 which looked promising (I played around with the DIR switches), but it doesn't seem to create any output.

My knowledge of batch files and their commands is pretty limited. Running Windows 10.

TIA

Nigel

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Input the date(dd/mm/yyyy):
set /p compDate=
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%compDate%") do set compDate=%%c%%b%%a

echo Input the directory:
set /p directory=
SET Exit=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt

pushd "%directory%"

(for /F "tokens=1-5*" %%a in ('dir /s /od /tc /a-d') do (
   set "fileDate=%%a"
   if "!fileDate:~2,1!!fileDate:~5,1!" equ "//" (
      for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%x in ("!fileDate!") do set fileDate=%%z%%y%%x
      if !fileDate! geq %compDate% (
         set "fileSize=               %%e"
         echo %%a  %%b %%c %%d  !fileSize:~-16! %%f
      )
   )
)) > %Exit%

popd
```

Comment: I would use brief Powershell commands. For example: (dir -recurse | where { ((get-date('14.09.2022'))-$_.LastWriteTime).days -lt 7 }).FullName"

Comment: Many thanks. As I'm not at all familiar with Powershell (please forgive my ignorance), does your line of code need to be put into a script? (As opposed to CMD where a line of code can just be executed at the prompt).

Comment: I think such inclusion is wrong way. But admins do it acceptably like this: **powershell -nop -c "(dir -recurse|where { ((get-date('15.09.2022'))-$_.LastWriteTime).days -lt 7 }).FullName"**

Comment: Again, many thanks. I tried that from command prompt, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I misunderstood you, you can go deeper into the topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles)

```
forfiles /P FOLDER_PATH\ /S /D -7
```